# Рожа, рожистое воспаление и рог

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Есть такое заболевание - рожистое воспаление. То есть, вокруг раны образуется (насколько я знаю) ороговевшая кожа.
При этом можно скорчить рожу или нарисовать смешную рожицу.
У меня ощущение, что слово "рожа" родственно слову "рог", и, если в первом случае все понятно, то какая связь между смешной рожей и рогом?

Comment: Об этом было с месяц назад. Происходит от французской "красноты"(rouge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть, правда, попытки толкования похожестей типа "ража-рожа-рог":
http://www.gelendshik.ru/yazik.htm

Answer (score 1):

Нет при рожистом воспалении никакого ороговения. Просто ярко-красный цвет воспаленного участка кожи. " III ро́жа III "название болезни". Вероятно, через польск. różа (см. ро́жа II), потому что кожа при этом приобретает ярко-красный цвет; см. Преобр. II, 209..."(М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973)

"рожа, рожица" (лицо) - скорее всего от локальных, диалектных форм "уродиться", "урода, врода"(красота), позднее приобретшее ироническую форму. К "рогу" (оружие) - никакого отношения, просто созвучно.